# How to use QVTKWidget

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I am working at a part of a big project.
My goal is it to show a `vtkRenderer` in a `QWidget`. For that I wrote this class:

```
CModelViewWidget::CModelViewWidget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent)
{
    _qVtkWidget = new QVTKWidget(this,Qt::Widget);
    _rend = vtkRenderer::New();

    this->showVTK();

    _qVtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(_rend);

}
```

where `_qVtkWidget` is a `QVTKWidget`, `_rend` a `vtkRenderer` and `showVTK()` a function that adds a sphere to `_rend`.

I am able to compile this things, but when I want to test them the program crashes. The error message is:

```
[pathToProject]/qtCT/qtcreator-build/bin/mabviewer: symbol lookup error:[pathToProject]/qtCT/qtcreator-build/lib/libplugwdgt_modelviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QVTKWidgetC1EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE
```

I am using VTK5.8, QTCreator 2.4.1 with QT 4.7.4 and cmake. I linked the project and VTK and showing a normal `vtkRenderWindow` works fine. Is there something else to do, before `QVTKWidget` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My setup is a little different, but the code works.  Setup: Qt x64 4.8.4 and VTK 5.10, using VS2010 x64 compiler.

First, add a verticalLayout widget to the main UI screen.  I suppose any of the other layouts would work, but I haven't tried them.  In the C++ editor try:

```
 _qvtkWidget = new QVTKWidget;
 ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(_qvtkWidget);
 ui->verticalLayout->update();
 _qvtkRenderer = vtkRenderer::New();
 _qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow->AddRenderer(_qvtkRenderer);
 _qvtkRenderer->SetBackground(0,0,0); 
 _qvtkRenderer->Render();
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set renderwindow in QVTKWidget and share interactor of that render window and add renderer to render window as:

```
..
renderWin->addRenderer(_ren); 
QVTKWidget1->SetRenderWindow(renderWin);
renderWin->SetInteractor(QVTKWidget1->GetInteractor());
```